# Edit object of an array using Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

I am developing my first app using Vuejs + Laravel and I am facing a problem that I couldn't solve until now!

I have an array of object and I need to edit a single of then without delete and add a new one! I have made a **JS Bin** to show what I need!

**[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/tucubo/edit?html,js,output)**

When you click in EDIT and start to typing your new value the original value edits as well but I need to change the original value only after the user hit the save button!

Anybody can help me?

PS: I will update my database and then show the new value on the table!

Is there anyway to duplicate my record as I do on the edit function without sync then?

**JS**

```
new Vue({

 el: 'body',

 data: {
   cache: {},
   record: {},
   list: [
       { name: 'Google', id: 1 },
       { name: 'Facebook', id: 2 },
     ],
 },

 methods: {
   doEdit: function (record) {
     this.cache = record;
   },
   edit: function (record) {
     this.record = _.cloneDeep(record);
     this.cache = record;
   }
 }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <form class="form-horizontal" @submit.prevent="doEdit(record)">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-el:record-name v-model="record.name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:15px">
          <button type="submit" class="col-xs-12 btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  <hr>
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Actions</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr v-for="r in list">
         <td class="text-center" style="width:90px"> {{ r.id }} </td>
         <td> {{ r.name }} </td>
         <td class="text-center" style="width:90px">
           <span class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" @click="edit(r)"><i class="fa-fw fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the old object with the cloned-updated one.

```
   doEdit: function (record) {
     var index = _.indexOf(this.list, this.cache);
     this.list.splice(index, 1, record);
   }
```

https://jsbin.com/ruroqu/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That's what I've looking for! Thanks Vedovelli!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save the value only after user submitted, you should not bind the record directly such as `v-model="record.name"`.

And we can use [`Vue.set`](http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-set) to change attributes of the original record.

Let's try: [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/qunaveduju/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: in case I have more than one field is there a way to do it easier then set a var for each field? For one field form it works perfectly but when you have a bigger form it is gonna be quite complicated!